# Codeigniter : append one array in other one

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

Hi i am trying to append one array in other one. When i do print_r() for new and old one this is what i get
 **new one**

```
 Array
(
    [0] => [1,2,3,4,5,6]
)
```

**old one**

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => [1,2,3,4,5]
    )
```

i am looping arrays like this but that's not working , Please help me to if i am doing something wrong

```
  foreach($newarray  as $value){

    array_push($oldarray, $value);
}
```

Comment: Just use `array_merge($newarray, $oldarray); `

Comment: gives me this  Array
(
    [0] => [1,2,3,4,5]
    [1] => [1,2,3,4,5,6]
) i want to push all of these to first index

Comment: Check https://3v4l.org/PVQr1

Answer (score 0):

use array_merge() function like

```
$merged_arr = array_merge($oldarray,$newarray);
```

it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this.

Assuming that both `$oldArray` and `$newArray` have only one item each.

```
$oldArray = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]];
$newArray = [[7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]];
$oldArray[0] = array_merge($oldArray[0], $newArray[0]);
var_dump($oldArray);
```

var_dump outputs

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=12)
      0 => int 1
      1 => int 2
      2 => int 3
      3 => int 4
      4 => int 5
      5 => int 6
      6 => int 7
      7 => int 8
      8 => int 9
      9 => int 10
      10 => int 11
      11 => int 12
```

Or the exact same results with `foreach` loops

```
$oldArray = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]];
$newArray = [[7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]];
foreach($newArray as $items)
{
    foreach($items as $key => $value)
    {
        $oldArray[0][] = $value;
    }
}
var_dump($oldArray);
```

For my money `array_merge` is the way to go.

In case you are wondering about the syntax shown.

`$oldarray[] = $value;`

and

`array_push($oldarray, $value);`

produce exactly the same results. The PHP evaluator produces the same machine code that actually executes. The first syntax requires a lot less typing and is, IMO, easier to read.

I am also using the short syntax to create arrays.

```
$oldArray = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]];
```

and

```
$oldArray = array(array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6));
```

produce the same results. Which would you rather type and/or read?